# Microsoft Sculpt keyboard not working with 2018 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, keyboard, usb

I have a brand new Microsoft Sculpt keyboard and mouse, and a 2018 MacBook Air. The keyboard works only occasionally, and often stops after a few keystrokes. The behaviour is either to not work at all, severely lag, or drop most keystrokes.

The USB receiver is plugged into a hub. I've tried the hub and keyboard on another computer and it works perfectly, so I assume there is no issue with either of them.

I've also tried swapping the hub to the other port on the MacBook Air, and I face the same issue.

What else can I try?

Comment: have you tried connecting the receiver directly (sans hub)?

Comment: Yah, plug it directly into the Mac, failing that it may not be (fully) compatible with macOS.

Comment: I can't plug in directly - it's USB-A and the Mac only has USB-C.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I am having the same problem with my 2019 MBP

Comment: does it work. I am facing the same isssue